# UITableViewCell wrong layout after selection in swift

Tags: image, uitableview, swift, alamofire

I try create tableview with default tableview cell. Each cell have imageView and title. Image loaded asynchronously from server. I use Alamofire framework for this purpose.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let CellID: NSString = "Cell"
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style:  UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: CellID)

        cell.textLabel!.text = "test #\(indexPath.row)"
        var imageURL = repArray[indexPath.row]["image"]!!

        cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named: "recept")

        Alamofire.request(.GET, imageURL).response() {
            (_, _, data, _) in

            let image = UIImage(data: data! as NSData)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                if let cellToUpdate = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
                    cellToUpdate.imageView!.image = image
                }
            })

        }

        return cell
    }
```

But when I select any tableview cell the size of the imageview changes.

[image: Before selection]
[image: After selection]

Why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` or `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath` method? If you do, could you show what it looks like? Looks like that's the part where you change the layout of the cell.

Comment: Is your problem solved?  I am hitting exactly the same problem.